# java.net.http import - not found

Tags: java, azul-zulu, pi4j

I am working in Intellij with Java 11. I want to use `import java.net.http.httpclient` in my project but the import statement is not found.

Background:

I am compiling on my Windows 10 Workstation to build for deployment on a Rasp Pi Zero W. The version of Java that I am using (SDK) is Azul Java 11.0.13.

When I type in import java.net.http.httpclient java.net is found but the http is not.

I have setup Intellij to use Java 11 AFAIK.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I get the import to work?

Comment: Did you add it to `module-info.java` ( `requires java.net.http;` )?

Comment: No - what is module-info

Comment: That fixed it. Suggest it as a answer and I will mark it.

Comment: Starting with java 9 every project should have (though it's not mandatory) `module-info.java`, search for it. If you have it in your project, add `requires java.net.http;` into it.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with java 9 if project has `module-info.java` that's the place were all non-default modules should be declared so that they can be used.

In your case it'd look as follows:

```java
module ModuleName {
    requires java.net.http;
}
```

For more details you could read:

- https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html